# APNS PUSH for multiple app id (Multiple .p12 certificate) from one Java/Tomcat server

Tags: java, apple-push-notifications, javaapns

I am using notnoop library for sending APNS push. My server is build on java and hosted on tomcat/apache webserver (One static IP). I have 2 iphone application which is on app store. Both having there app id and certificates. When I try to send push from our server, it is sending push only to that App which certificate initialise first time. Suppose I have 2 application, AppA and AppB, they have 2 different app id, AppIDA and AppIDB and they have there own certificates (.p12) CertiA and CertiB.
After I restarted our tomcat server and if one push initiated let say AppA, it will deliver to device successfully. If the another push initiated for another App AppB, it will not deliver to device. I cant understand why this happen. Both certificate I tested individually and both are working fine. Below is java code.

This code creates new instance every time for each App AppA and AppB.

```
import com.notnoop.apns.APNS;
import com.notnoop.apns.ApnsService;
import com.notnoop.apns.ApnsServiceBuilder;


//This is the class to send the PUSH 

public class APNSConnectionImpl extends MessagingConnection {

//APNS Builder, using notnoop library
     ApnsServiceBuilder apnsServiceBuilder = null;
//APNS Service, using notnoop library
    ApnsService apnsService = null;


// This function is use to send PUSH
// Parameters:
// deviceAndPaylodiOS : List of Devices and Payload
// appRegistrationKey : Name of the certificate, It could be AppA Certificate or //AppB Certificate. The certificate comes at runtime and both certificates copy and //past in a specific folder lat say /var/apncertificate/AppACertificate.p.12 and     /var/apncertificate/AppBCertificate.p.12


    @Async
    @Override
    public HashMap<String, String> sendMessagePool(Map<String, String> deviceAndPaylodiOS, String appRegistrationKey) 
            throws ApplicationException {

        initializeApnsServices(appRegistrationKey);

        if (deviceAndPaylodiOS == null || deviceAndPaylodiOS.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

// Sending Push to all devices,
        deviceAndPaylodiOS.forEach((key, value)->{
            apnsService.push(key, value);
        });

        if (apnsService != null) {
            apnsService.stop();
            apnsService = null;
            apnsServiceBuilder = null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void initializeApnsServices(String appRegistrationKey) throws ApplicationException{

        if (apnsServiceBuilder != null) {
            apnsServiceBuilder = null;
        }

        apnsServiceBuilder = APNS.newService();

        try {
            String certPath = "/var/apnscertificates/"+ appRegistrationKey;
        apnsServiceBuilder.withCert(certPath,Constants.APNS_PASS_CERTIFICATE).withProductionDestination();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new QuinchyApplicationException("APNS certificate problem");
        }

        if (apnsService != null) {
            apnsService.stop();
            apnsService = null;
        } 

        apnsService = apnsServiceBuilder.build();
    }
}
```

Comment: so you tried sending to App A first, it worked and then to App B, it failed right ???
what about the reverse case ?
Sending to App B first and then to A ?
is it sending to App B in this case?

Comment: Hi Arun, Yes it is correct. It works for reverse case as well. Whose ever initialise first, works.

Comment: need more code to analyze, pls post the calling place also and this entire function

Comment: Thanks Arun, I have updated the code in actual post, please have a look.

Comment: APNSConnectionImpl object is creating every time new for each certificate.

Comment: if apnsservice.push() is an asynchronous call, then please remove these lines below that call 
if (apnsService != null) {
            apnsService.stop();
            apnsService = null;
            apnsServiceBuilder = null;
 }

Comment: because object might be garbage collected, even before it finish push to all devices

Comment: Also, appRegistrationKey is different for each run right?

Comment: Yes, appRegistrationKey is different for each device.

Comment: apnsService.push may be an asynchronous call, so don't stop the service immediately after for loop

Comment: Thanks Arun, APNS started working when I removed the apnsService.stop() code. But after removing this code the thread get started crashing after sending last PUSH to device. Is it require to stop the apnsService after sending the PUSH? And do we need to retain the apnsBuilder and apnsService throughout the server life cycle as kind of singleton for both the certificate?

Comment: Could you post crash crash log ?

Comment: Yes, It's safe to stop apns service after sending pushes. it would lead to memory leak otherwise. But make sure you are calling stop() only after sending all notifications. Since push is an asynchronous call, calling stop() halts the apnsservice even before it finishes the loop